# How to infer type based on key value?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to infer the type of `getAllRaces()` to be `() => Race[]`.

So far I tried:

```
type CollectionMap = {
    races: Race[]
    horses: Horse[]
}

type Race = {
    date: Date
}

type Horse = {
    name: string
}

type UnionizeKeys<T> = {
    [k in keyof T]: k
}[keyof T]

type CollectionName = UnionizeKeys<CollectionMap> // "races" | "horses"

// Failed attempts

const getAll1 = (name: CollectionName) =>  [] as CollectionMap[name];
//  Type 'name' cannot be used as an index type.(2538)

const getAll2 = (name: CollectionName) =>  [] as CollectionMap[typeof name as const];
//  A 'const' assertions can only be applied to references to enum members,
//    or string, number, boolean, array, or object literals.(1355)

const getAll = (name: CollectionName) =>  [] as CollectionMap[typeof name];

const getAllRaces = () => getAll('races')
// ❌ const getAllRaces: () => Race[] | Horse[]
// ✅ const getAllRaces: () => Race[]
```

#### [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwRAxsAlnAdgWQIZhQC8UA3gFBRVQBOeKEAzgFxQBK9EA2gLqXUALODUZNWACWGje5AL7lyoSO07Ey-KgBM8wCKwAiOiHIVLokkdBIVqULHgC2eqI2A10WAOYnF4aAFUsTCCALwgAaQgQRgAeABUAPjUbai4AaygPKDSouAAzKDieVjS5dNyCotM-WERkNGCAOUcrKEDg9DDI6Jj4JFQMbHwwJIB6UagAIjoGRkmoAB8poUs5hXGoADE8dGRNKB1dBzBgRgUUbFcoTwhgAEEkAEY1AAp7J1Y++sGsZqcASmISSgvAOjFq-QaQwIXHeEB4AG5yBtALwbgFKdwo1ADkcKxUBQeCwWDgwCgACNoABXUT7PDgwmZLCaCAADygZgAdC8AEwAVgAzAAOf7nS6km73JDc15wz51AZNFqAojA0F0iHfYLDLhmfJ2Fpg-FixHIiboqB3KBYi5YVx4umiGg-cEErBQbAIEDk6AEMAIdAQfbAOC0CB5CA0CBYWbskNRykOKBOBwUkQAGndNBcbg8ngzWATqYzZLgiAghIzeBodBAGeE7rJACsBlB-bo6AhGFzHvzebyReQbVcJQ8EDKWnLIT8-hBlaqeIavgroWAdX49XCTYOxddbqOODGSC857vJQgXliZkwsSKNoAZciNtvFe6QB7EUGPQJUDFBSws0j4DZAFByR9hxfBA3xYD8TzfXggA)

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the return type of `getAll()` to depend on the `name` input, you can make it [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `K`, the type of the `name` input, where `K` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `keyof CollectionMap` (which is just the same as your `CollectionName` type, written more directly than the roundabout `UnionizeKeys`):

```
const getAll = <K extends keyof CollectionMap>(
    name: K
): CollectionMap[K] => [];
```

The return type is just the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `CollectionMap[K]`, the type of the property of `CollectionMap` with a key of type `K`.

Let's test it out:

```
const getAllRaces = () => getAll('races')
// const getAllRaces: () => Race[]
const getAllHorses = () => getAll('horses');
// const getAllHorses: () => Horse[]
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwRAxsAlnAdgWQIZhQC8UA3gFBRVQBOeKEAzgFxQBK9EA2gLqXUALODUZNWACWGje5AL7lyoSO07Ey-KgBM8wCKwAiOiHIVLokkdBIVqULHgC2eqI2A10WAOYnyKbK6hPCGAAQSQ1AB4AaSgIAA9dLE1GKABrCBA4ADNYRGQ0TFwCAD4ACg07R2co8gBKVngkVAxsfDAuKJ5iYqheAG4FPywAoNCkDgYUklLa7sDgsIRSgHI6SeXa8gB6LaghkYXxzhYoGbmJ7j594HmxhAtRKdPZoh7RxZWhS0YNgZ29-w3d5IB5iZ5zUG8IA)